# how can I fill an “fill between” area by point meta?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

All, consider the following MWE:

How to fill the `blue!20` area by `point meta` e.g., `point meta=x^2` ?  I mean the filling should be like a contourplot, with colors determined by some function (like x^2).

I had tried a lot, but nothing worked. Do you have any ideas?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
    \addplot+ [name path=A] {sin(360*x)};
    \addplot+ [name path=B] {cos(360*x)};
    \addplot  [blue!20] fill between [of=A and B]; 
      %% how to fill this area by point meta e.g., point meta= x^2
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: how to fill the blue!20 area by point meta e.g., point meta=x^2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, to be honest. Do you mean that the filling should be like a contourplot, with colors determined by some function (x^2)?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.    So sorry for the confusion. Yes,  that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Right. I don't actually know how to do that offhand, but someone else might. I'll try something though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Many thanks, anyway.

Comment: In addition to the previous precisions, you mean to have the surface filled with a varying color based only on the x value, so sort of a shading that varies horizontally, is that right ?

Comment: @BambOo. Hi, BambOo. I am so sorry for the confusion. I mean the color should be based on the point meta i.e., coordinates,  rather than the x value. (I just take x^2 for example.)   In 3D plot,  I made a 2D slice of the function z=exp(-x^2-y^2),  and the area under the curve has been colored by the point meta  z=exp(-x^2-y^2).   see the picture link : 
    https://tva1.sinaimg.cn/large/007S8ZIlgy1gevro1np6zj30nz0hl76w.jpg.   But I dont know how to fill the area by point meta in 2D plot.

Comment: Can you add this new information based on the 3D plot? This should help formulated an answer